# html5 video not work in android native webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have the following link

http://stage.diabetesmasterclass.org/Upload/myclinic/SAM/visit1/sam_storyline_output/story_html5.html

it contains an html5 video and I have tried to load it inside a webview in my android app

it keep loading and never run, I tried to enable javascript and to add a lot of configuration but did not work also

I even tried to use AdvancedWebView sdk to render it, and in this case it loads but did not run anything

can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load page using below code:

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected AgentWeb mAgentWeb;
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.web_content);

        mAgentWeb = AgentWeb.with(this)
                .setAgentWebParent(mLinearLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1))
                .closeIndicator()
                .setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient)
                .setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient)
                .setMainFrameErrorView(R.layout.agentweb_error_page, -1)
                .setAgentWebWebSettings(getAgentWebSettings())
                .setSecurityType(AgentWeb.SecurityType.STRICT_CHECK)
                .setOpenOtherPageWays(DefaultWebClient.OpenOtherPageWays.ASK)
                //.interceptUnkownUrl()
                .createAgentWeb()
                .ready()
                .go("http://stage.diabetesmasterclass.org/Upload/myclinic/SAM/visit1/sam_storyline_output/story_html5.html");
    }

    private WebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);

        }
    };

    private WebViewClient mWebViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.i("Info", "BaseWebActivity onPageStarted");
        }
    };

    public @Nullable
    IAgentWebSettings getAgentWebSettings() {
        return AgentWebSettingsImpl.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mAgentWeb.getWebLifeCycle().onPause();
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mAgentWeb.getWebLifeCycle().onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mAgentWeb.getWebLifeCycle().onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == 2) {
            mAgentWeb.getIEventHandler().back();

        }
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Top"
            android:textSize="22dp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/web_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bottom"
            android:textSize="22dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

using this [Webview](https://github.com/Justson/AgentWeb)

update Output look like [this](http://prntscr.com/njd2e4)

Comment: yes it works but why it force my layout to be landscape, I want it only to appear in the part of screen and do not hide the rest of UI, another thing do you know how to access javascript from this webview to get data from it ?

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail please check my update answer and output.

Comment: I tried but is did not work, so I downloaded the library from gitlab and modify one line of code in it and then everything ok now, Thanks a lot for your help